# 1602 LCD Module showing garbage output

Tags: lcd, arduino, iot

I connected 1602 LCD with Arduino( Without I2C) to print Hello World, but after printing hello world for few seconds it starts showing garbage values
Here's my code

```
    #include<LiquidCrystal.h>

    int Contrast = 145 ;

    LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);


    void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    analogWrite(6,Contrast);
    lcd.begin(16,2);
    //  Serial.begin(115200);
    }

    long result = 0;
    void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Hello ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("World ");

    delay(500);
    }
```

Comment: Connection problem? Connection problem destroyed your LCD? Hard to tell  from here. Your code isn't the reason why it only worked a short time. Is it ok again after a power_off ?

Comment: Once i disconnected the RW connection, then the garbage output stopped which means the LCD is fine, moreover it does not show wrong output if the display is changed constantly(like displaying random numbers or time), The garbage output is shown if the value is predefined as in "Hello World" and is not changing constantly.

Comment: Also the garbage output appears after few seconds after displaying the output(in this case Hello World)